# Why does INSERT INTO fail with 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I know that there's literally dozens of questions about the same error, and I've checked them all. Most of them have to do with someone misusing the `SELECT` statement, and I couldn't find any with a problem similar to mine.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       port=3306,
                       user='root', 
                       passwd='password',
                       db='nhl')
cur = conn.cursor()

#some code...

player = td.string.strip()
player = player.split(' (')
tID = teamList.index(team)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO players (Name,G,A,P,PlusMinus,PIM,S,H,BKS,GVA,TKA,TeamID) 
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (player, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, tID))
```

`pymysql.err.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong. All database columns are `INT` except for `Name` which is `VARCHAR`. This is coded in Python 3.4 using pymysql.

Comment: I assume there's no newline in your code after `TeamID)` and you only added it here for readability?

Comment: Yeah that whole execute statement is on one line

Comment: ahhh it's the simple errors that you never notice! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
player = player.split(' (')
```

After this line, `player` is a list of strings (instead of a string), so `cur.execute` won't let you interpolate it as the value for the `Name` column.

A simple way of finding these bugs is trying to replace the values with literals, like:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO players (Name,G,A,P,PlusMinus,PIM,S,H,BKS,GVA,TKA,TeamID) 
                   VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                          ("playerName", 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 123))
```

which would work, and you'd know to look for the error elsewhere. See: [How to debug by splitting the problem space.](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2789958)